# The solid infinite cylinder is a regular surface?

Tags: differential-geometry

I have to proof that the set $C=\{ (x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3: x^2+y^2\le1\}$ and the set $D=\{ (x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3: x^2+y^2\lt1\}$ are regular surfaces.

I alredy know that the infinite cylinder, $C_0 = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3: x^2+y^2=1\}$, is a regular surface. I made to functions that covers it. Let $U=(0,2\pi)\times \mathbb R$, and $X_1,X_2:U \to \mathbb R^3$ with $X_1(u,v)=(\cos u, \sin u, v)$ and $X_2(u,v)=(\sin u, \cos u, v)$. $X_1$ covers $C_0 \backslash \{(1,0,z):z \in \mathbb R\}$ and $X_2$ covers $C_0 \backslash \{(0,1,z):z \in \mathbb R\}$ and then $X_1(U) \cup X_2(U)=C_0$.

I imagine that C and D are like onions, they have an infinite number of layers, each of them an infinite cylinder with its radious $r \le 1$.

So for each "layer", for a $r\in (0,1)$, I can construct two functions defined in $U$, that cover it, $X_1^r(u,v)=(r\cos u, r \sin u, v)$ and $X_2^r(u,v)=(r\sin u, r\cos u, v)$. So if $r=1$, we are back with $C_0$. The problem i found it that if $r=0$ it becomes the set $\{(0,0,z):z\in \mathbb R\}$; and that is not a surface. So neither C nor D are regular surfaces. Am I right?

Comment: In the definition of the second $C$, is it possible a condition such as "$z = 0$" got omitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A note about terminology - usually what people call "a regular surface" is a **two dimensional** embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (so the charts on the surface have open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as their domain) but sometimes, "a regular surface" is used to refer to any embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or even of a general manifold) who is not necessarily two-dimensional. I prefer to keep the term "surface" for two dimensional things but there are books that don't follow this convention.

Anyway, the set $C = \{ (x,y,z) \, | \, x^2 + y^2 < 1 \}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and so is a **three-dimensional** submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (that can be covered using one chart - the identity chart). You are correctly feeling that something is wrong because there are at least three problems with what you are purposing:

1. Your charts don't even cover $C$ (they miss $\{ (x,y,z) \, | \, (x, 0, v) \, | \, |x| < 1, v \in \mathbb{R}$).
2. When $r = 0$, your map is not a chart.
3. The image of each chart should be an open subset of $C$ and the chart needs to be a homeomorphism onto the image. This fails badly here (make sure you understand why)

The set $C' = \{ (x,y,z) \, | \, x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \}$ is a three dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ **with boundary** so you need to make sure your definition of "regular surface" allows that and if so, construct charts modeled on $\mathbb{H}^3$.

Comment: Yes, I correct myself and you help to see my mistakes.